# Optimizing PostgreSQL Find Sproc

Tags: postgresql, optimization

Throughout our code base, we have many finds on the database that allow a variable number of parameters to be searched in essentially any combination. Most of these have been generically written as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getObject(p_field1 INTEGER, p_field2 INTEGER, 
  p_field3 INTEGER, p_field4 INTEGER, p_field5 INTEGER)
    RETURNS SETOF Object
AS $_$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM Table_ent_Object
    WHERE (p_field1 = 0 OR Field1 = p_field1)
      AND (p_field2 = 0 OR Field2 = p_field2)
      AND (p_field3 = 0 OR Field3 = p_field3)
      AND (p_field4 = 0 OR Field4 = p_field4)
      AND (p_field5 = 0 OR Field5 = p_field5);
END;
$_$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It was pointed out by someone that knows SQL but not PostgreSQL that this would not perform well in SQL because it would not allow for a well-optimized query plan to be developed beforehand, but she did not know if PostgreSQL would act the same.

Is this a poor way to build these queries? And if so, is there a better way?

As a note, we used to hard-code every possible parameter combination in the sprocs, but this became difficult to maintain as adding, removing or changing a parameter in the sproc affected so much, it was very easy to miss a combination of parameters that needed to be updated, or to order the parameter checks incorrectly and fall to the wrong case.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres would probably use a bitmap index, and then AND/OR the results accordingly for quick retrieval.

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12553.1135634231@sss.pgh.pa.us